# Oracle SQL Cases, Comparing Columns in Different Tables and Joins

Tags: sql, oracle

Instructions:

- Select columns `EName` and `VehicleName`
- If `EName` doesn't own a vehicle, display Null as `VehicleName`.

Relevant SQL tables and columns:

```
Table         | Columns
--------------+-------------------------
Emp           | EmpNo, EName
Vehicle       | VehicleId, VehicleName
EmpVehicle    | EmpNo, VehicleId
```

My current attempt is:

```
SELECT Emp.EName, Vehicle.VehicleName
FROM Emp
INNER JOIN EmpVehicle ON Emp.EmpNo = EmpVehicle.EmpNo
INNER JOIN Vehicle ON EmpVehicle.VehicleId = Vehicle.VehicleId
```

The above query works in the sense that it displays all employee names with a `EmpVehicle.VehicleId` and `Vehicle.VehicleName` entry but I have no clue how to include employee names that don't have a vehicle with joins involved.

I have been able to determine that not all `EmpNo` values in the `Emp.EmpNo` column are in the `EmpVehicle.EmpNo` column and that my above query only displays the names of employees whose employee number are in the `EmpVehicle.EmpNo` column.

How would you write a case that looks at if an employee number in column `Emp.EmpNo` is not in column `EmpVehicle.EmpNo` and if it is not return Null in the displayed `VehicleName`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should `LEFT JOIN` to keep data from your `Emp` table that doesn't match on your `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT Emp.EName, Vehicle.VehicleName
FROM Emp
LEFT JOIN EmpVehicle
ON Emp.EmpNo = EmpVehicle.EmpNo
LEFT JOIN Vehicle
ON EmpVehicle.VehicleId = Vehicle.VehicleId
```

Comment: This works! Sorry it turned out to be as silly as not using the proper joins. I thought the query would hide rows had a column entry when a NULL value was not specifically set as NULL regardless of the join used.Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use left join so you can see the emp that don't have vehicle

```
SELECT Emp.EName, Vehicle.VehicleName
FROM Emp
LEFT  JOIN EmpVehicle ON Emp.EmpNo = EmpVehicle.EmpNo
LEFT  JOIN Vehicle
ON EmpVehicle.VehicleId = Vehicle.VehicleId
```

And check for EmpVehicle.EmpNo is null  for select the emp.EName that don't have vehicle

```
SELECT Emp.EName 
FROM Emp
LEFT  JOIN EmpVehicle ON Emp.EmpNo = EmpVehicle.EmpNo
WHERE EmpVehicle.EmpNo is null
```